# Git Repository vs Git branch based development

Tags: git, repository, branch

I am working on how to migrate to progressive web app from the existing chrome apps as the chrome app will cease to exist by mid next year. While we are working on the migration to pwa we want to ensure that the existing chrome app continues to exist till we stop releasing it.
In order to do continue working in a parallel manner, we want to go forward with either of the two approaches.

- Create a separate a git branch which will only take care of migrating
  and adapt our codebase to the progressive web app while we continue
  to develop features on the master branch. At the end of the day we
  will merge master into our_new_branch so that the new branch is up to
  date with the master.
- Fork out the existing git repo and create a new repo so that we only
  work on the migration part in it and apply a patch from the existing original repo at the end of the day.

Both the approaches will have significant amount of changes to make them consistent with each other. Which is the better approach of the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach (fork) still allows for regular merge from the main repo.

And it isolate nicely any change and branches specific to the migration in its own repo. So I would chose that approach.

But the most important is the development workflow: can you merge regularly between master and the migration branches? If yes, the integration between the two (repos or branches) will be easier than working separately on the migration and then (too late in my opinion) trying to merge the main master branch.